# ElasticSearch hits have no fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am having a problem where when I run a search on elastic using the java api I get back results... but when I try and extract values from the results there are no fields.

ElasticSearch v5.3.1

Elastic API: org.elasticsearch.client:transport v5.3.0

My code:

```
SearchRequestBuilder srb =   client.prepareSearch("documents").setTypes("documents").setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH).setQuery(qb).setFrom(0).setSize((10)).setExplain(false);

srb.addDocValueField("title.raw");
SearchResponse response = srb.get();

response.getHits().forEach(new Consumer<SearchHit>() {

        @Override
        public void accept(SearchHit hit) {
            System.out.println(hit);
            Map<String, SearchHitField> fields = hit.getFields();

            Object obj = fields.get("title.raw").getValue();

        }

    });
```

When the forEach runs the obj is always coming back null. Fields has an item in it with the key of title.raw and it has a SearchHitField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields is only used when you are trying to obtain stored fields. By default you should obtain fields using the source. With the following code samples I'll try to explain it.

```
PUT documents
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "store": true
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT documents/document/_bulk
{"index": {}}
{"title": "help me", "description": "description of help me"}
{"index": {}}
{"title": "help me two", "description": "another description of help me"}

GET documents/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "help"
    }
  },
  "stored_fields": ["title"],
  "_source": {
    "includes": ["description"]
  }
}
```

Next the response, notice the difference between the stored field Title and the normal field description.

```
{
  "_index": "documents",
  "_type": "document",
  "_id": "AVuciB12YLj8D0X3N5We",
  "_score": 0.14638957,
  "_source": {
    "description": "another description of help me"
  },
  "fields": {
    "title": [
      "help me two"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I see. So what you're saying is that none of my fields are marked as stored which is why they arent available. But that I can access the data from the source.

Comment: Following your advice I used the source:
`Map<String, Object> source = hit.getSource();`
Which let me access all the fields. Thanks!